# LIbsvm error rate

Tags: libsvm

How would you run libsvm on windows, How to get after training and predicting the error rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding installation on Windows, I quote from the [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) website: "For MS Windows users, there is a subdirectory in the zip file containing binary executable files."

As far as how to use SVM, take a look at their [guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf).

Comment: Ok, I was reading that `C:\libsvm\windows\svm-train  C:\libsvm\windows\fileTrain.txt` for training.   
`C:\libsvm\windows\svm-predict C:\libsvm\windows\filetTest.txt C:\libsvm\windows\fileTrain.txt.model C:\libsvm\windows\output_file` for predicting, but, Error rate?, does it give it when executes??